# Having problems with CMake and CLion for SFML

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, sfml, clion

I've been trying to use CMake to use SFML in CLion on Mac OS X, but I've been running into problems. I have been trying to link it statically, but I'm running into problems with dependencies that I don't know how to fix.

Here's my CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(First)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=lib++")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(First ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/Users/18sunbri/Documents/SFML-2.2-osx-clang-universal/cmake/Modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK NEVER)

find_package(SFML COMPONENTS graphics window system REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${main.cpp} ${SFML_Libraries})
```

When I try to load the CMake file, I get an error.

```
Error:SFML found but some of its dependencies are missing ( FreeType GLEW libjpeg)
```

I know it has to do with dependencies, and I tried reading the `FindSFML.cmake`, but I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have FreeType, GLEW and libjpeg installed?

Comment: @Peter I'm pretty sure that they are included with SFML. http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/start-vc.php

Comment: That link is for visual studio on Windows. You probably need to install FreeType, GLEW, and libjpeg development packages like @Peter suggests (in a way cmake can find them).

Comment: Also, your `target_link_libraries` will need to be fixed to have `First` as the first argument, not `${main.cpp}`

Comment: @JohnDrouhard Do you know how I would install the dependencies? Would I have to do it separately?

Comment: Actually on the SFML website it says "On Windows and Mac OS X, all the required dependencies are provided alongside SFML so you won't have to download/install anything else. Building will work out of the box."

Comment: @FourScore True, the deps are provided. On OS X however, static linking is not really recommended. At least I didn't put much effort in testing it, especially with cmake. You'd better off using dynamic libraries (which works for sure).

Comment: @Hiura I had some trouble with dynamic libraries, you do know where I can find out how to do it properly?

Comment: @FourScore there are a few links in the OS X tutorial but if you have a specific question open a new one here.